# custom class vs specific selector for lists (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to write better CSS, I've seen some Harry Roberts conferences and read about the BEM methodology.So by now what I understand in general is that:

1. You should keep things modular and reusable
2. Make custom general classes and avoid nesting
3. Never use ID's (or almost never)

My question refers to the second one: in the case of a list, let's say I want to edit the color for both the normal and `:hover` state. Should I add a custom class to each `<li>` element or a custom class to the `<ul>` and refer to the `<li>` inside it?

Here is an example to better illustrate what I mean.

```html
<h3>Custom class for ul</h3>
<ul class="list">
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
</ul>


<h3>Custom class for li</h3>
<ul>
 <li class="list__element">One</li>
 <li class="list__element">Two</li>
 <li class="list__element">Three</li>
 <li class="list__element">Four</li>
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
 .list li {
  color: black;
 }
 .list li:hover {
  color: red;
 }

 .list__element {
  color: black;
 }
 .list__element:hover {
  color: red;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: This is a rather difficult question to answer as it's largely down to preference and coding style. Personally I think slight nesting is fine (A `li` inside a list is pretty much the textbook place to use nesting) and would prefer that to bloating your markup with classes on every `li`. But that may not adhere to the BEM mindset. I think in BEM you wold be required to use, for example, a `.red` class and apply it to all element you would like to style.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using BEM, try applying classes to EVERY element. That way you are dealing with the same level of specificity across the board, and you won't have to deal with priority orders.

So to answer your question, having .list__element:hover is exactly what you want.

I provided a more elaborate example, to demonstrate modularization. Notice how I added a new module "utensils".

Hope this answers your question!

```css
.kitchen {
  &__utensils {
  }
}

.utensils {
  &__utensil {
    &:hover {
    }
  }
}

// this gets compiled to

.kitchen

.kitchen__utensils 

.utensils

.utensils__utensil

// that is exactly what you want because you are avoiding specificity. Which means you will never have to fight with your selectors, which means you will never have to use important tags.
```

```html
<div class="kitchen">
  <ul class="kitchen__utensils utensils">
    <li class="utensils__utensil"></li>
    <li class="utensils__utensil"></li>
    <li class="utensils__utensil"></li>
    <li class="utensils__utensil"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Specificity should be your friend, not your enemy.

Comment: @Alohci you're totally right friend, but the whole point of BEM is to avoid cluster balls in your stylesheets. For example when you get to your media queries, you want to override something, then you see nothing changing only to realize that you were too specific.. then you're thinking "ugh, why was I that specific... now I am going to use important tags"... Happens to all of us :P BEM makes sure that never happens.

Comment: Thanks, @zsawaf, I guess at the end of the day is the difference between writing more vs avoiding some specificity headache in the future. Another thing that the classes for an element might get too long. Example ``<ul class="kitchen__utensils utensils  u-floatRight">`` but definetelly avoid specificity is great.